# How to find mode from an array

Tags: arrays, mode

I have been trying to get this prototype for finding mode of an array to work but it is not returning the right thing, could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
  int mode(int array[], int size)
  {
      int x;
      int mode = 0;
      int largest = 0;

     for (x = 0; x < size; x++)
     {
         if (array[x] > largest)
         {
             largest = array[x];
             mode = x;
         }
      }
    return mode;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all if that's c++ Arrays are numbered from 0, so x should be 0 in the for. also x should be checked against < size. Other then that the code is good.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say it is just C. I'd did however change the 1 to a 0. But should I still check x < size? Also would I just change the <= to a <?

Comment: If it's c the 0 start rule still applies. Yes if you keep <= you will check an element outside the array, that's an invalid read. i don't know how You pass the array size. but size is usually the count of elements, so if size = 4 and you have 4 elements in the array you will read an element outside the array :)

Comment: hmm, well I changed it and it is still giving me incorrect results.

Comment: I mean I changed it in my actual code, I just forgot to edit that part.

Answer (score 0):

In the question you've mentioned that  " prototype for finding **mode** of an array " ,but this program is intended to find the position of the largest number in an array, because

```
mode = x;      // x is the value of i which in-turn is the position of element in the array
```

and the value of mode is returned. So the position of the largest element counting from the zero'th element's position is shown.

If you want a program to **find the mode** (element/number that occurs most often) in an array, here it is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mode(int array[], int size);
int main()
{
    int Num[100],size,ret_Val,i;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    printf("%d  ",size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&Num[i]);
    }
    ret_Val=mode(Num,size);
    printf("Mode of the array is %d",ret_Val);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int mode(int array[], int size)
{
    int cntMde = 1;
    int i;
    int cnt = 1;
    int num = array[0];
    int mode = num;

    for ( i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == num) 
        {
            cnt++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (cnt > cntMde) 
            {
                cntMde = cnt;
                mode = num;
            }
            cnt = 1;
            num = array[i];
        }
    }
    return mode;
}
```

And the output is

```
Mode of the array is 44
```

Comment: hmm well I thought it was working but it was just coincidence, that much be close though

Comment: Was that answer useful? ,if yes please accept the answer

Comment: But it's working for me, I'm editing and giving the complete program, try to execute it.

Comment: Oh  it's probably not working because in my program you enter in what you want the input to be to find the mode of an array with a varying size.

Comment: Have you tested this program ?

Comment: Yeah and it works, unfortunately I guess I need to do something different when the values in the array are randomized, and the size varies.

Comment: Do you need that of code? (to accept the number from the user input and finding the Mode of that array)

Comment: If you could that would be sweet.

Comment: Uhh well the function for finding mode is the same as it was, the other part I'm not having a problem with. I just cannot get the mode to show up.

Comment: just use getch(); before return 0; then you'll be able to see the output. Let me know the results

Comment: For some reason it seems 90% of the time the number is just the first number in the array instead of actually being the mode.

Comment: The problem "mode doesn't show up" is after displaying the mode value return 0; function is used which cause the program to exit. So if we give getchar(); just before return 0; it waits untill a key is pressed, and after a key press it goes to the next statement ie; return 0; causing the program to exit... Try it

Comment: that's actually not even doing anything different, should I be putting something in the parentheses of getchar():?

Comment: Not neccesary, using getchar(); is just only for displaying the result untill a key is pressed.

Comment: Well putting it in there didn't do anything different for me.

Comment: Wait DONOT use getchar(); JUST USE getch();

Comment: That just gives me a compile error saying undefined reference to getch

Comment: I've just updated the code which neither have warnings nor error's . And I've personally tested it, try it

Answer (score 0):

I have analyzed four ways to calculate mode of the array:

- If range of numbers in the array is small then use counting sort - O(N) time, (N) space but very efficient
- Index elements in the array in hash table - O(N) time, O(N) space
- Sort the array and then count successive equal elements - O(NlogN) time, O(1) space
- Partially sort the array but skip partitions smaller than current candidate - O(NlogN) time, O(1) space but much more efficient than fully sorting the array because many partitions will be skipped

You can find source code for all four methods and performance comparison in this article: [Finding Mode of an Array](http://www.sysexpand.com/?path=exercises/array-mode)